# Returning Array in USER_INT userFunc leads to <!--INT_SCRIPT output

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a userFunc which I call via

```
lib.random = USER_INT
lib.random {
  userFunc = My\Plugin\UserFunc\Functions->random
}
```

when I return a Array and try to access it is fails.

```
<v:variable.set name="random" value="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.random')}" />
{random.max}
```

When I try to debug out it I get some `<!--INT_SCRIPT` string

Did anyone know the problem and a Solution?

/e:

I would like to make the problem a little clearer by describing the Szenario.

I have a Plugin with a Login form. When the User logs in I set a JWT with various basic informations (name, email).
This Informations have to be displayed on various places around the Website, not only on one page (for example profile page). Some cases are prefilled forms or just silly "Hello, Paul" stuff.

So when I first log in (Fresh browser, no cache) then I read "Hello, Paul" after I log out and log in with a another Account (Lets call it "Peter") then It still is written "Hello, Paul" , nor "Hello, Peter". When I clear my browser Cache then everything is fine.

Maybe this helps maybe to solve my dilemma. :)

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but you can't use f:cObject like a function call with user_int.
If you look at https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/UserInternalContentObject.php you can see that it returns exactly this string.

Comment: Wen I `<f:fromat.raw`  the data I get a json string. But ok, when that's the case that its not useable that way then I accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

`USER_INT` are not Cached, so the values for this are replaced after the cache is build up.

I think `f:cObject` is the wrong way. Implement an own ViewHelper to get the same data should be an better way.

```
<?php
namespace My\Plugin\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;

class RandomViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $escapeOutput = false;

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return string
     */
    public static function renderStatic(
        array $arguments,
        \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
        RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
    ) {
        return rand();
    }

}
```

Now you can use it like following:

```
{my:random()} or <my:random />
```

Comment: It has to be not cached, thats why i tried it with USER_INT. We tried it with a Viewhelper but they are also cached.

Comment: With `renderStatic` the ViewHelper is not cached.

Comment: Well that's what I tried, as a test case I returned a `rand();` and it was always the same number.

Comment: hast it maybe somthing to do with the `$renderingContext->getVariableProvider()->add($arguments['name'], $value);`  part? I currently just `return` my data.

Comment: This should also work with return instead of adding an new variable

Comment: Maybe your browser cache is making the trouble. Just tried an rand() ViewHelper. After disabling the browser cache the rand number was always changed

Comment: Ok, but I wold like to always get complete fresh data. With the userFunc it worked :/

Comment: if `USER_INT` is used typo3 don't send cache headers. So if you don't want to cache the pages in the browser cache you must disable the header cache: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-sendcacheheaders

But i recommend to let the browser cache on. Maybe you can load the data by ajax or reduce the cache time in your .htaccess

Comment: "With renderStatic the ViewHelper is not cached" is a misconception, this has nothing to do with caching ability. It only has to do with which way the VH can be called once the template is compiled. It is also not true that USER_INT causes TYPO3 to suppress cache headers - but config.no_cache or an active user login does!

Comment: It is not recommended to "leak" variables; with the notable exception of `f:variable` which is designed for that purpose. Normally, a ViewHelper that adds a template variable, should 1) assign the variable, 2) then call `$renderChildrenClosure()`, 3) remove the variable again and 4) return the output of rendered children (or set it as tag content if tag based ViewHelper).

Comment: Thanks Claus Due of clarify the "RenderStatic". But about "USER_INT causes TYPO3 to suppress cache headers": In the linked documentation page their say that cache headers are only send if "No *_INT or *_EXT objects were on the page (e.g. USER and USER_INT)" and other requirements are given

Comment: I edited my example ViewHelper so it doesn't "leak" variables.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: uncached parts in TYPO3 are replaced in the generated page output string using markers and cannot communicate in the direction intended here. Selectively caching, disabling cache or detaching the data from the main request (with XHR or other) are the only possible methods.**

It should be clear that USER_INT achieves its functionality by *string replacement in the generated page body*. This means, among other things, that:

- You can never pass the output of a USER_INT to anything in Fluid, not even if the entire page is uncached. You will effectively be passing a string containing `<!---INT_SCRIPT...` (the entire marker).
- You can however generate USER_INT from Fluid, which ends up in the generated page, which is then replaced with the rendered object (use f:cObject to render a USER_INT or COA_INT).

Then there are the use case context considerations. First of all, a cookie (in practice) changes the request parameters and should be part of the cache identifier that your page uses (it is not this way by default). Second, if said cookie changes the way the page renders (and it does, given your use case) this *will* cause trouble when the page is cached. Third, the page output changing based on a cookie indicates perhaps sensitive information or at the very least user-specific information.

Taking the above into account your use case should do one of the following things:

1. Either render the entire chunk of output that changes based on cookie, as USER_INT. That means wrapping the entire Fluid output and rendering it all without caching. Note that template compiling still happens (and you can use f:cache.static to hard-cache certain parts if they never change based on request parameters).
2. Or add the cookie value to the `cHash` (page hash value) so that having the cookie set means you request a specific cached version that matches the cookie. This is the preferred way if your cookie's values is generally the same for many users (e.g. it contains a selected contact person from a limited list and stores that in a cookie).
3. Or, in the case that your output contains actually sensitive information, require that the *content element or page* is only available when logged in with a specific group. This has two purposes: first, it protects the page from being viewed without authentication - but second, it also makes the page content not cache or be cached with the *frontend user group ID as part of the cache identity*.
4. Refactor to XHR request and make whichever endpoint it uses, a USER_INT or manually disabled cache context, then load the data. Or set the actual data in the cookie, then use JS to insert the values where needed.

Hopefully that clarifies the different contexts and why they can't communicate in the direction you're attempting; even if they had been exchanging strings instead of arrays.

See also: `.cache` sub-object in TypoScript which is where you would be able to craft a unique cache identifier for use case 2 described above.

Comment: Thank you for the Detailed explanation. Honestly I fell a bit overwhelmed :)
I think we stick with the `<v:render.uncache`

Comment: I have a Question to this part:
> First of all, a cookie (in practice) changes the request parameters and should be part of the cache identifier that your page uses (it is not this way by default)
How could I achieve this? Like adding the token to the cache identifier. I've google a but gut couldn't find anything usefull

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757939/typo3-6-2-performance-typoscript-select-typoscript-cache has some relevant information, the "TypoScript cache" answer is the one you need. You need to create an "identifier" that uses TypoScript to read and transform a cookie value (for example to create an md5).

Comment: I tried it out but it didn't changed anything. I've created a md5 out ofthe token and stored it into a cooke and then add this cookie as a key for the cache. It didn't changed. I think the problem here is still the browser cache. (I also tried it with a lifetime of 1)

Comment: If the same URL can be used both without and with a cookie, by the same user, and the user receives the page once with a "revisit-after" that's high, then your only option is to lower the revisit-after value. If you told the browser previously the URL was okay to cache, only a force-reload from the user will change that. If you use logins: make the URLs unique. If public: set revisit-after sufficiently low.